# jQuery from googleapis.com is blocked in mainland China

Tags: feature-request, bug, china

I am a user from mainland China. And I understand that the great wall blocked Google.

Is is possible holding the jQuery library on Stack Overflow servers instead of fetching it from `googleapis.com`?

Currently, it takes 5 minutes to fail loading jQuery when opening a single page.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack Overflow (the company) does not care at all, so you have to resort to third-party solutions.